# How to place all unique values into a lookup array in JavaScript for a Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I've been [working through a problem with others](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327271/adding-feature-property-values-to-filter-drop-down-option-in-leaflet-instead-of/327336?noredirect=1#comment533741_327336) on 1) grabbing id's from a GeoJSON, 2) placing those id's into a dropdown menu on a Leaflet map, 3) and enabling functionality to allow the user to choose an id, after which the map will filter and zoom to the chosen location.

We've got the control,

```
L.FeatureSelect = L.Control.extend({ 
  options: {
    position: 'topright',
    title: 'Name, Clear',
    lookupProperty: 'name',
    lookupInFeatureProperties: true
  },    
  initialize: function (features, options) {
    this.featureCollection = features;
    L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
  },
  onAdd: function(map) {
    this.div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-featureselect-container');
    this.select = L.DomUtil.create('select', 'leaflet-featureselect', this.div);
    var content = '';       
    if (this.options.title.length > 0 ) {
      content += '<option>&nbsp;' + this.options.title + '&nbsp;</option>';
    }
    if (this.options.lookupInFeatureProperties) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        content += '<option>' + this.featureCollection.features[i].properties[this.options.lookupProperty] + '</option>';
      }
      }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        content += '<option>' + this.featureCollection.features[i][this.options.lookupProperty] + '</option>';
      }
    };
    this.select.innerHTML = content;
    this.select.onmousedown = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    return this.div;
  },
  on: function(type,handler) {
    if (type == 'change'){
      this.onChange = handler;
      L.DomEvent.addListener(this.select, 'change', this._onChange, this);          
    } else {
      console.log('FeatureSelect - cannot handle ' + type + ' events.')
    }
  },
  _onChange: function(e) {
    var selectedItemKey = this.select.options[this.select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (this.options.lookupInFeatureProperties) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        if (this.featureCollection.features[i].properties[this.options.lookupProperty] == selectedItemKey) {
          e.feature = this.featureCollection.features[i];
          break;
        }
      }
      }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        if (this.featureCollection.features[i][this.options.lookupProperty] == selectedItemKey) {
          e.feature = this.featureCollection.features[i];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    this.onChange(e);
  }
});

L.featureSelect = function(features, options) {
  return new L.FeatureSelect(features, options);
};
```

And the map, which clears content when choosing the title (Name, Clear) using data from [this location](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json).

```
var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{attribution: 'Tiles &copy; CartoDB'});
var map = L.map("map",{layers: [baseLayer], center: [-23.88, -62.75], zoom: 4});

$.getJSON( "world.geo.json")
 .done(function(data) {
   var select = L.featureSelect(data);
   select.addTo(map);
   select.on('change', function(e) {
     if (e.feature === undefined) {
       return;
     }
     var feature = L.geoJson(e.feature);
     if (this.previousFeature != null) {
       map.removeLayer(this.previousFeature);
     }
     this.previousFeature = feature;  
     map.addLayer(feature);
     map.fitBounds(feature.getBounds());
   });
 });
```

The problem is that I'd like to feed the script a geojson with many non unique `lookupProperty` values. i.e. a polygon layer with many Brazil or many Canada values. Currently, the script will return all values under the "lookupProperty", meaning many duplicates end up in the dropdown menu.

How may I grab and place all non unique id's into dropdown menu array?

From my understanding, if the dropdown menu has all non unique id's, when a user selects the unique id, all features with that property value will be filtered and displayed on the map, which is what we want.

Comment: You should mention in your question that control is based on  Leaflet.CountrySelect plugin, written by Anika S. Halota.

Comment: Yes, this is derived from [Anika S. Haolta](https://github.com/ahalota/Leaflet.CountrySelect),  [TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327529/how-to-place-all-unique-values-into-a-lookup-array-in-javascript-for-a-leaflet-m), and [Johan](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json). On the backs of giants we stand. Thank you for being patient with someone so new to javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it has to be noted that control mentioned in the question is modification of [Leaflet.CountrySelect](https://github.com/ahalota/Leaflet.CountrySelect) plugin, written by Anika S. Halota.

To achieve unique lookup keys in menu, the following changes were made to control:

1. At the load time (`onAdd` method) all lookup keys are stored into internal array where they are sorted and made unigue.
2. Internal method `_sortUnique` was added to get sorted and unique lookup keys.
3. When features are selected to be displayed (`_onChange` method), loop goes through all the features to get possible multiple features that correspond to selected lookup value.

```
L.FeatureSelect = L.Control.extend({ 
  options: {
    position: 'topright',
    title: 'Name, Clear',
    lookupProperty: 'id',
    lookupInFeatureProperties: false
  },    
  initialize: function (features, options) {
    this.featureCollection = features;
    L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
  },
  onAdd: function(map) {
    this.div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-featureselect-container');
    this.select = L.DomUtil.create('select', 'leaflet-featureselect', this.div);
    var content = '';
    this.lookupArray = [];
    if (this.options.title.length > 0 ) {
      content += '<option>&nbsp;' + this.options.title + '&nbsp;</option>';
    }
    if (this.options.lookupInFeatureProperties) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        this.lookupArray.push(this.featureCollection.features[i].properties[this.options.lookupProperty]);
      }
      }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        this.lookupArray.push(this.featureCollection.features[i][this.options.lookupProperty]);
      }
    };
    this.lookupArray = this._sortUnique(this.lookupArray);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.lookupArray.length; i++) {
      content += '<option>' + this.lookupArray[i] + '</option>';
    }
    this.select.innerHTML = content;
    this.select.onmousedown = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    return this.div;
  },
  on: function(type, handler) {
    if (type == 'change'){
      this.onChange = handler;
      L.DomEvent.addListener(this.select, 'change', this._onChange, this);          
    } else {
      console.log('FeatureSelect - cannot handle ' + type + ' events.')
    }
  },
  _onChange: function(e) {
    e.features = [];
    var selectedItemKey = this.select.options[this.select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (this.options.lookupInFeatureProperties) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        if (this.featureCollection.features[i].properties[this.options.lookupProperty] == selectedItemKey) {
          e.features.push(this.featureCollection.features[i]);
        }
      }
      }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
        if (this.featureCollection.features[i][this.options.lookupProperty] == selectedItemKey) {
          e.features.push(this.featureCollection.features[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    this.onChange(e);
  },
  _sortUnique: function(array) {
    array.sort();
    var last_i;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      if ((last_i = array.lastIndexOf(array[i])) !== i) {
        array.splice(i + 1, last_i - i);
      }
    return array;
  }     
});

L.featureSelect = function(features, options) {
  return new L.FeatureSelect(features, options);
};
```

Since multiple selected features are now possible, adding and removing is done through `L.featureGroup`:

```
$.getJSON( "world.geo.json")
 .done(function(data) {
   var select = L.featureSelect(data);
   select.addTo(map);
   select.on('change', function(e) {
     if (this.previousFeatures != null) {
       map.removeLayer(this.previousFeatures);
     }
     if (e.features === undefined) {
       return;
     }
     this.previousFeatures = L.featureGroup();
     for (var i = 0; i < e.features.length; i++) {
       this.previousFeatures.addLayer(L.geoJson(e.features[i]));
     }
     map.addLayer(this.previousFeatures);
     map.fitBounds(this.previousFeatures.getBounds());
   });
 });
```

Comment: TomazicM you're amazing! This helps tremendously! Thank you!